# What is the best way to print to the default printer in PHP?

Tags: php, printing

I have a PHP application with a standard interface that involves a grid of data.

When you click on a row in that grid, it takes you to a details page.

I'd like to have a "Print" button on that page, which prints a specific set of information to the default printer attached to the client machine.

Is this possible from PHP?  I have found things online about printing to a printer attached to the **server**, but that's not really what I want.  Do I need to do this from JavaScript, instead?

Comment: If it's a client-side printer then you need to do it on the client side.

Comment: OK, that's kind of what I expected.  I wasn't sure if PHP had any platform-agnostic way of printing to the client.

Comment: @JosephStyons Clients don't know or care that PHP is running on the server.  For all the client knows, it's just requesting a file on the server like anything else.  PHP fundamentally has nothing to do with the client.  Now, if you're talking about a printer hooked up the server, or on the same network as the server, that is a different story entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using php. But you can do this in Javascript.

Just add `window.print()` on click on a specific element and this will open a print dialog.